# Why does List<T> implement IList<T>, ICollection<T> and IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#

If you go to definition of `List<T>` you would see the following:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
```

`IList<T>` already inherits from both `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Wouldn't it have been sufficient if `List<T>` only implemented `IList<T>`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it makes no difference in this case. In some cases it *can* make a difference, if you're using a base class which already implements an interface but you wish to reimplement it yourself explicitly - but in this case there's no base class (other than the implicit `object`) and it would have behaved exactly the same way.

Contrary to my recollections, I don't believe there's a difference in the way the class is represented in metadata whether the code explicitly declares all the interfaces or not. Here's an example:

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IBar : IFoo {}

class FooBar1 : IBar {}
class FooBar2 : IBar, IFoo {}
```

Both ildasm and Reflector show the same information for `FooBar1` and `FooBar2`... it shows both of them implementing `IBar` and `IFoo`.

In other words, we can't tell whether the original source code for `List<T>` actually specifies all the interfaces or not. Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't - but it doesn't matter either way.

EDIT: For completeness, I also checked the cases where you're extending two interfaces with another interface. I can't find a difference in the metadata in that case, either. I'm sure I remember some situation in which it was evident, but I can't find it now.

Comment: So since there is no base class. It doesn't make a difference. Then why the developers inherited those two interface 'again'?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I love you man. I want to implement your IBrain. Can I inherit "your" base class ?

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep: I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it would. `IList<T>` itself implements the other two.

The object browser shows you *all* the interfaces the class implements, whether directly (`IList<T>`) or indirectly (`ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, *through* `IList<T>`).

Comment: you mean it's just a trick the object browser does to make things easier on us?

Comment: Well, if you want to put it that way. I really think it's because the browser's code simply lists all implemented interface, without caring to filter out those extended by others.

Answer (score 4):

That's not the way it was actually coded behind the scenes.  That's just what tools like Reflector show you when it turns the IL back into C#.

Comment: @Incognito: codeviewer generates it from metadata the same way reflector does.

Answer (score 3):

If you looked at the source code:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

You can observe that the signature is:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
```

This can only mean that the metadata browser de-normalizes the inheritance hierarchy for us.