# Why List<> implements IList

Tags: c#, .net, ilist, generic-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (does it really?) List implement all these interfaces, not just IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilist)

Out of curiosity, what is the reason behind generic **List<>** implementing non-generic interface **IList**?

Sample code

```
IList<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);

//compiles but ArgumentException thrown at run time
((IList)list).Add(new object());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does List<T> implement IList<T>, ICollection<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224081/why-does-listt-implement-ilistt-icollectiont-and-ienumerablet) or [Why does List<T> implement all these interfaces not just IList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilist)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Not really a duplicate, since that question is about the generic interfaces, while this one is for the non generic ones. EDIT: This extends to all you drive by closers.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 I am asking about **non-generic** interface. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For backwards compatibility with pre-generics code (or code that chose to use IList rather than the generic alternative).  Probably a dupe of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilist which has the following answer discussing backwards compatibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-it-really-listt-implement-all-these-interfaces-not-just-ilist/4817419#4817419

Comment: @SwDevMan81: @bentayloruk has picked the correct duplicate. You were close, though.

Comment: @oleksii - No problem.  Hopefully those links will help.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 @bentayloruk you right. Thanks for the info! Voted to close.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote, since there's a particular advantage to the fact that List<T> implements non-generic IList (or more singificantly, ICollection): it makes it possible to determine the number of items in a List<Giraffe> that's passed as an IEnumerable<Animal>, without having to actually enumerate them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post by Eric Lippert: [So many interfaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx). He has some great insights, as always

Make sure to read the whole thing, but here's the quote that answers the question:

> **Why then does List implement IList?**
>
> It is a bit odd, since List for any
>   type other than object does not
>   fulfill the full contract of IList.
>   It's probably to make it easier on
>   people who are updating old C# 1.0
>   code to use generics; those people
>   were probably already ensuring that
>   only the right types got into their
>   lists. And most of the time when
>   you're passing an IList around, it is
>   so the callee can get by-index access
>   to the list, not so that it can add
>   new items of arbitrary type.

Comment: Link's now broken - luckily the relevant part was quoted in the body of the answer. Unfortunately, the Wayback Machine has no copy of that blog post either. If anyone finds the post somewhere, please update the link.

Answer (score 3):

`IList` has *particular* significance. In particular, it forms the hub of much data-binding, and largely acts as the canonical way of saying "I'm a bunch of items".

Note also - generics are not convenient via reflection; data-binding struggles a bit with them, preferring non-generic APIs. It helps that in the binding scenario, the *convention* used by the data-binding code is that if the list *also* has a non-`object` indexer:

```
public SomeType this[int index] {get;}
```

then assume the items are `SomeType. Which of course`List` satisfies admirably.

So; this provides plenty of backwards compatibility with existing code *and* data-binding support via this.

Answer (score 2):

Backwards-compatibility.  This way it can be injected into older frameworks/libraries That are 1.0/1.1, or were migrated from 1.0/1.1 and not fully refactored, or used with objects in the 2.0+ .Net frameworks that still sport the same interfaces they did in 1.0/1.1, without having to forgo type-safety in your new code.

Comment: then why not for ICollection<T> to ICollection...??

Comment: It is also a great convenience when dealing with Reflection.

Comment: @Srinivas: The Collection<T> *class* does implement the non-generic ICollection, IList, and IEnumerable interfaces, as well.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy - If `ICollection<T>` included `ICollection`, then that would *require* generic collections to implement the non-generic interface. Such a requirement is unnecessary and cumbersome. This is a different circumstance than what is in the original question. `IList<T>` also does not include `IList`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe List implements a version of IList because it is trivial to do, and may be useful, as you wouldn't need to wrap your list in another to pass it into another class.

However it does do a type-check on any items you attempt to add and will throw if they don't match.

Comment: it is *trivial* to implement almost all interfaces, but types do not do that. There is a greater reason behind it.

Comment: @oleksii: My original response was based on it being a read-only version, so was attempting to exemplify that "Why not" would be sufficient logic. Should have edited once I realized it was read-write to better wording, but there is another response available so it is a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is for you to be able to have a List of ILists of different types.
For example -

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
List<string> strings = new List<string>();

List<IList> lists = new List<IList> { ints, strings};
```

Comment: that is an interesting answer list of lists :) However,as we figured out it is needed for the backward compatibility. Thanks for a try.

Comment: @oleksii: It's worth noting that `List<T>` could have implemented `IList<T>` in type-safe fashion if one didn't mind having `IList.ReadOnly` return a different value from `IList<T>.ReadOnly`.  In other words, would could have had a mutable `List<T>` behave as a type-safe read-only `IList`.